# Xbee python wirelessly receiving data over serial interface

Tags: python, serial-port, raspberry-pi3, xbee

I am using Xbee connected to Raspberry pi3, API-mode=2 and sending data from xbee over serial interface which works well. However, I need to read data that is coming to the same Xbee(this part does not work well). Please find my code below which contains script for both transmission and reception of data over serial interface:

```
ser=serial.Serial(PORT, BAUDRATE)
while True:
    #SEND DATA
    msg=[0x10,
         0x00,
         0x00,
         0x00,
         0x00,
         0x00,
         0x00,
         0x00,
         0xFF,
         0xFF,
         0xFF,
         0xFE,
         0x00,
         0xCC,
         0x66,
         0x00,
         0x00,
         0x01,
         0x00,
         0x03,
         0xFF,
         0x01,
         0x00,
         0x01,
         0x77,
         0x00,
         0x1D]
    ser.write(chr(0x7e)+
              chr(len(msg)//256)+
              chr(len(msg)%256))
    ser.write(''.join(chr(x) for x in msg))
    check=(0xFF - ( sum(msg) & 0xFF ))
    ser.write(chr(check))

    #READ DATA
    msg=[0x90,
         0x00,
         0x13,
         0xA2,
         0x00,
         0x41,
         0x88,
         0xA5,
         0x2C,
         0xFF,
         0xFE,
         0x00,
         0x66,
         0x00,
         0x00,
         0x01,
         0x00,
         0x03,
         0xFF,
         0x01,
         0x00,
         0x01,
         0x77,
         0x00,
         0x1D]
    ser.write(chr(0x7e)+
              chr(len(msg)//256)+
              chr(len(msg)%256))
    ser.write(''.join(chr(x) for x in msg))
    check=(0xFF - ( sum(msg) & 0xFF ))
    ser.write(chr(check))
    data = ser.read()
    print(data)

ser.close()
```

I am able to send data. However read script is printing me the following:

```
~


▒

}
3
▒

A
▒
▒
▒
▒
▒
▒
f



▒





w


▒
```

I would appreciate any help for this. I prefer to serially read and write without using python library. However, I am open to suggestion that would work for my case.

Answer (score 0):

First, you might want to leave your `ser.write()` calls outside of your `while True:`, otherwise you're sending a lot of packets.

Try to design your big loop to always check for bytes on the serial line, and to trigger your writes after certain events happen (like maybe there's a keypress, or a certain amount of time has elapsed).

It looks like you're receiving a frame -- `~` is a `0x7E`.  Does `ser.read()` always return a single character?  You could print it with `print(hex(ord(data)))` to get the hex value of the character's ordinal value and it might start to look like the list of hex values you're expecting.

And you said you preferred not to use a Python library, but you might want to consider [Digi's python-xbee library](https://github.com/digidotcom/python-xbee) to reduce the amount of time you spend getting bare-bones working code, and focus your time on application-layer coding.